# Use of the built-in Microsoft Translator with excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, translate

I want to parse a text in a cell to the built-in Microsoft translator, and then copy the translation to another cell.

If I record a macro and go to review>translate; copy-paste the translation, the code only contains the paste bit, and no code is recorded for calling the translator.

Is there a way to do this using the built-in Microsoft translator?

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually set up the call to the translator in the cloud. Code example here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b001845-b212-492f-9b8c-e055fd00f905/vba-code-bing-translator?forum=microsofttranslator